# Activiti move to a particular task on event like runtime wiring

Tags: java, activiti

We want to model the process such that in case of any outside event, we want the process to go to a particular step.
Now the process can be at any step but as soon as the event occurs, it should be back to a particular task. We can not attach an event listener to any particular task.

Let me explain this with a sample business process.

[image]

Lets say the task is in Approve task or Pending stage. Now in case of reset event I want to move the process to Review Task state.
I have only shown 3 steps in the example but there could a lot more task. All I am looking for a way to listen to an external event ( via API) and reset it to be back at Review Task.
How can we achieve this in activiti ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, from your description it sounds like you are really looking for a case management solution. Given events trigger micro processes within a specified list of "Case events".
While Activiti does not include case features (CMMN) the "Flowable" project which has taken Activiti to the next level includes both a BPMN and CMMN engine and should certainly meet your requirements. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks !! I looked at Flowable and it makes sense in this scenario to use CMMN instead of pure BPMN. Unfortunately, I can not take that jump for now but in the future, Let me find a workaround till we migrate.

Comment: That's fair, but be aware that Flowable (like Camunda) is an Activiti derivative. Flowable specifically builds on the old Activiti open source product. Migration of any existing Activiti project should be quite trivial and it seems now may be a good time to make that decision.